# Space curves in Vector Analysis and proofs

Tags: vector-analysis

given the space curve $x=a\cos t$, $y=a\sin t$, $z=bt$ show that $k=\dfrac{a}{(a^2+b^2)}$

My solution :

Assuming $a,b$ and $c$ are positive: $k(a^2+b^2)=a$

$0\leq t\le2\pi$

$X^2+y^2=a^2$

Midpoints: $(x_0,y_0)$ 
With $x=x_0+a\cos t$ and $Y=y_0+b\sin t$

I haven't managed to get past here. Please assist

Comment: the a and b in k=a/(a2+b2) are squared

Comment: Please say what is $k$ : it is the curvature : you are looking for the curvature of an helix, which is constant (independent of $t$). See (http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/Curvature.aspx) and (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Helix.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant $\;r(t)=(a\cos t,\,a\sin t,\,bt)\;,\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi\;,\;\;a,b>0\;$, we have:

$$r'(t)=(-a\sin t,\,a\cos t,\,b)\;,\;\;r''(t)=(-a\cos t,\,-a\sin t,\,0)\implies$$

$$r'\times r''=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\-a\sin t&a\cos t&b\\-a\cos t&-a\sin t&0\end{vmatrix}=\left(ab\sin t,\,-ab\cos t,\,a^2\right)\implies$$

$$\kappa=\frac{\left\|r'\times r''\right\|}{\left\|r'\right\|^3}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2b^2+a^4}}{(a^2+b^2)^{3/2}}=\frac a{a^2+b^2}$$

If you do re-parametrization by arc length:

$$s=\int_0^t\left\|r'(x)\right\|dx=\int_0^t\sqrt{a^2+b^2}dx=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}t\implies t=\frac s{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

so our curve is now

$$r(s)=\left(a\cos\frac s{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\,,\,\,a\sin \frac s{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\,,\,\,\frac{bs}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)\implies$$

$$T(s)=r'(x)=\left(-\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin\frac s{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\,,\,\,\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos\frac s{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\,,\,\,\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)\implies$$

$$T'(s):=\frac{dT(s)}{ds}=\left(-\frac a{a^2+b^2}\cos\frac s{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\,,\,\,-\frac a{a^2+b^2}\sin\frac s{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\,,\,\,0\right)\implies$$

$$\left\|T'(s)\right\|=\frac a{a^2+b^2}$$

exactly as before, of course.

Comment: Typo in $\kappa$, no $\sqrt{}$ in denominator.

Comment: @Ng You're right, of course. To save time and effort in these things I do a lot of "copy&paste"...and that's what happens. Thank you, I shall correct.

Comment: Thank you!! I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \boldsymbol{r} &= (a\cos t,a \sin t, bt) \\
  \dot{\boldsymbol{r}} &= (-a\sin t,a \cos t, b) \\
  |\dot{\boldsymbol{r}}| &= \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \\
  \ddot{\boldsymbol{r}} &= (-a\cos t,-a\sin t,0) \\
  \kappa &=
  \frac{|\dot{\boldsymbol{r}} \times \ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}|}
       {|\dot{\boldsymbol{r}}|^3} \\
  &= \frac{|(ab\sin t,-ab\cos t,a^2)|}
          {\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)^{3}}} \\
  &= \frac{a\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)^{3}}} \\
  &= \frac{a}{a^2+b^2} \\
  \dddot{\boldsymbol{r}} &= (a\sin t,-a\cos t,0) \\
  \tau &= 
  \frac{\dot{\boldsymbol{r}} \times
        \ddot{\boldsymbol{r}} \cdot
        \dddot{\boldsymbol{r}}}
       {|\dot{\boldsymbol{r}} \times \ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}|^2} \\
  &= \frac{a^2b}{a^2(a^2+b^2)} \\
  &= \frac{b}{a^2+b^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Then the next part asks me to show that: T= b/(a2+b2). a and b are squared.